# How to change Jenkins home directory (~/.jenkins) when there is no jenkins installed

Tags: linux, jenkins

I never installed Jenkins on my server. All I have done was downloading .war file and tomcat is hosting it. By default it made a directory under my home directory (~/.jenkins) which Jenkins using for its own config and parameters.

Is there anyway to change the directory that Jenkins is pointing to? I need to move this directory.
I searched for that a lot but people all gave a solution for the case that Jenkins is installed already.

The server is running 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7', and Jenkins version is 1.642.4.

Comment: Jenkins is installed. Running it under tomcat counts has having it installed.

Comment: If it's not installed, what exactly do you think tomcat is hosting? What do you think the config and parameters are being used for?

Comment: Please, consider using RHEL 7.x.  It's been 5+ years since they cut the 6.x branch, and a full year has passed since they released 7.x so it's not a risky proposition.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the `JENKINS_HOME` location by adding an environment entry in the context container used by tomcat for the jenkins webapp (typically in `/etc/tomcat[VERSION]/Catalina/localhost/[context-name].xml`), like this:

```
<Context (..)>
    (..)
    <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="[your jenkins home]" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of Apache Tomcat you can specify startup parameters, including `JENKINS_HOME` for specifying Jenkins directory, in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` file:

```
$ cat setenv.sh

CATALINA_PID="${CATALINA_BASE}/tomcat.pid"
CATALINA_OPTS="-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=${JENKINS_HOME} -Xms1024m -Xmx8192m -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true"
```

In above example `${JENKINS_HOME}` is set an environment variable, but you can replace it by absolute path.

Please refer to Apache Tomcat [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) for more details.