# Home directory was not changed in Mint

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am using Linux mint 18.3. I am trying to change home directory for Jenkins. I created new directory, copied all data from old. After that I modified .profile (put there export `JENKINS_HOME=/home/alex/JenkinsHome/`), but nothing have happened.

Comment: What **should** happen?

Comment: Thanks for attention. I expected that localhost:9090- Manage Jenkins -Configure System- Home directory was changed to /home/alex/JenkinsHome/

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/196262/how-to-change-the-root-directory-for-a-linux-user - a user's home directory is not configured in `.profile`

Comment: Nico, thanks for your advice.

Comment: You should set the jenkins home directory in the tomcat context configuration file - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36587049/3303940).

Comment: Akos Bannerth, thanks a lot. Your advice solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Jenkins home directory by creating file : path to Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/jenkins.xml with

```
<Context>
    <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="path to home directory" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

One more time thanks for Akos Bannerth.